# How to access custom files in drupal multi site via url

Tags: multi-sites

My site folder structure for drupal multisite is as follow:

`-example.com.uk
--vendors-dir
---create.php`

How can i get the url example.com/uk/vendors-dir/create.php execute create.php?
As of now i get the 404 error when i execute example.com/uk/vendors-dir/create.php.

Comment: PHP execution within the vendor directory is blocked by a `.htaccess` file to prevent people from running code there.

Comment: @Neograph734 how to allow that. when i have vendors-dir in root folder i am able to execute create.php

Comment: You should not be willing to allow that. Code from the vendors directory is not intended to be ran directly. If you must, try including the from from another file outside of the vendor directory.

Comment: @Neograph734 it doesnt work if i create another file and try to execute.